# Succinct way of packing several memoized functions into an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function component with a bunch of memoized functions:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    const foo = useMemo(() => {...})

    const bar = useMemo(() => {...})

    const baz = useMemo(() => {...})
}
```

Instead of sending all functions as individual props, I want to pack them into a functions object:

```
const functions = {foo, bar, baz}
```

But this undoes the memoization, so I must also memoize the functions object:

```
const functions = useMemo(() => {
        foo, bar, baz
    }, [foo, bar, baz])
```

But having to list the functions twice is annoying.

Is there a way to list the functions only once, and still get a memoized functions object. (I do realize that I could list the function names somewhere outside the component function, and then somehow use that list in useMemo, but if possible I would like to list the functions inside the component function only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your maybe after something like ->

```
const {foo, bar, baz} = useMemo(() => ({
   foo: () => console.log('foo'),
   bar: () => console.log('bar'),
   baz: () => console.log('baz'),
}), []);

foo(); bar(); baz();
```

Note: If any of your functions require side effect, make sure you include in the dependency.  eg.  if `foo` used a value from props, eg.  Maybe foo was a lookup function that took a prop called id, you would put `[prop.id]` as the dependancy.

Also if you would like to avoid typing foo, bar, baz again, you could even use array destructoring.

eg..

```
const [foo, bar, baz] = React.useMemo(() => [
    () => console.log('foo'),
    () => console.log('bar'),
    () => console.log('baz'),
], []);

foo(); bar(); baz();
```

Of course using this technique, you have to make sure your functions are in the same order as your destructuored array.

A couple of things to note about combining your functions like this,.  If the dependency does change, all functions will be regenerated even if not required.  Eg, in my previous example, if foo depends on prop.id, but bar and baz don't , bar and baz will get regenerated too.  Generating function in JS is extremely fast, and just redefining the functions might be fine anyway and using useMemo would be overkill in my simple example.  But if your useMemo created functions based on some async callback, then using useMemo would have a real benefits.